# Write the repeating decimal a = .162162162162... (where the ‘162’ continues forever) as a fraction p/q in lowest terms

Tags: calculus

I have come to a roadblock in this problem, as our teacher wants us to solve it in a particular way. I've started by writing the decimal like this:

$.162162162... = 1.62(10^{-1})+1.62(10^{-4})+1.62(10^{-7})+...$

I know I'm supposed to turn this into a summation in this form

$$\sum_{i=???}^\infty 1.62(10^{???})$$
then turn it into a fraction by using this formula I THINK

$$\sum_{n=0}^m r^n=\frac{1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}$$

Can anyone help me finish up this problem?

Comment: Oh, it's much easier to note that $1000x=162+x$.

Comment: @lulu I realize it is much easier and understand how to do it the way you suggested, unfortunately I have to do it using summations

Comment: Ok, so then write your sum as $.162\times \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac 1{1000}\right)^i$   Just to say, though...the method used to sum Geometric Series is exactly the same as the method I recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $$\begin{align}0.162162162\ldots &= 0.162 + 0.000162 + 0.000000162 + \cdots\\ &= 0.162(1 + 0.001 + 0.000001 + \cdots)\\ &= 0.162(1 + {1\over 1000^1} + {1\over 1000^2} + \cdots) \\ &= 0.162\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({1\over 1000}\right)^n\right]\\ &=0.162\left({1\over 1- 1/1000}\right) \\ &={162/1000\over999/1000}\\ &= {162\over999}\\&= {6\over37}.\end{align}$$

Comment: this makes so much sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$.162162162... = .162+.162(10^{-3})+.162(10^{-6})+...$$

$$ = \frac {.162 }{1-0.001} = \frac {162 }{999} = \frac {6 }{37} $$